# Possible to attach to android app?

Tags: android

I am wondering if it is possible to "Attach" to an android app in such a way that you could see the code that is being executed at any given event. I am wanting to build an app that does certain things based on what another app is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can using a debugger from a PC, if the app has debugging enabled.  You can't just from another random app on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!